# Policy for Freeradius server

Tags: samba, freeradius

I have :

- Samba4 AD DC (v4.7.6 Ubuntu server 18.04) .
- Freeradius server (v3.0.20 Ubuntu server 18.04) .

  - joined DC
  - mariaDB
- Cisco WLC auth-acct with freeradius server :

  - SSID A , 10.0.16.0/24
  - SSID B , 10.0.24.0/24

How can i setup policy on freeradius server for user A or group A only access to one SSID ?